# How to check if there are at least two occurrences of an element in a list, only using append? - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've got an assignment where I have to define a predicate named two(X,L), which is true if the list L contains at least two occurrences of the element X, using **only the append predicate.** The right-hand side of any of my rules may use only append, or use the predicate two(X,L). So for example, my desired output would look like this.

```
two(x,[a,a,b,a,c,b,a]).
X = a
X = b

two(c,[a,a,b,a,c,b,a]).
FALSE
```

I've been trying to think of a way to do this, but based off of my knowledge of append the only predicate we could really use within `two(X,L)` is `append(X,X,L)`. Append isn't a true/false thing is it, it just tries to put X within L twice.

I don't need someone to solve the assignment for me, I just need a stepping stone because I'm confused as to how to accomplish this task only using append.

Answer (score 1):

```
two(X,List):-append(_,[X|Rest],List),append(_,[X|_Rest2],Rest).
```

Comment: This will give redundant answers sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean with redundant? If you like to ensure that two does not leave a choice point, you can add the cut operator (!) to the end of the body.

Comment: `?-two(X,[a,a,b,a,c,b,a]).
X = a
X = a
X = a
X = a
X = a
X = b
X = a`
Cut at the end of the body would be incorrect, and the question asked for a definition using only append.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the previous answer of @user27815, an alternative solution could look like the following code, in which the helper predicate needs to be integrated into the the `two` predicate:

```
two(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    two_helper(X, [Y|Ys]),
    \+ two_helper(X, Ys).

two(X, [_|Ys]) :-
    two(X, Ys).

two_helper(X,List) :- append(_,[X|Rest],List),append(_,[X|_Rest2],Rest).
```